# Регулярное выражение, проблема с пробельными символами

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, помогите с написанием регулярного выражения в одну строчку, пробовал заменять отступы на `\t` а где перенос строки на `\n` но все равно не работает выражение, а если вернуть все на место работает без проблем.

```
                    <b>
                      (.*?)
                    <\/b>
                    <br\/>
                    <i>
                      (.*?)
                    <\/i>
                    <br\/>
                    <br\/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не совпадет, выложите, пожалуйста, на pastebin то, с чем должна совпасть регулярка

```
$a = '                    <b>
                      some text
                    </b>
                    <br/>
                    <i>
                      some text
                    </i>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>';
$pat = '-\s*<b>\s*(.*)\s*</b>\s*<br/>\s*<i>\s*(.*)\s*</i>\s*<br/>\s*<br/>-';
var_dump(preg_match($pat, $a));
```

> пробовал заменять отступы на \t а где перенос строки на \n

в приведенной вами регулярке не отступы, а пробелы, плюс перенос строки на винде будет не просто \n, а \r\n

Comment: благодарю! теперь догнал.